# JPA Entity field type validation

Tags: java, jpa

I am relatively new to Spring and I want to create a form web app with using Spring Boot. Some users will create a form template and other users will fill that form. Users who want to create a template should create form fields. Every time a form field is created, the type of that field should also be inserted by users who create templates. For example, if `fieldType` is `short_answer` users who will fill it should fill it with a `String`, or if `fieldType` is `number` users who will fill it should fill it with an `Integer`.

Therefore I created two `@Entity` annotated classes which are `FormField` and `FormResponse` here are they:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FormField {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String fieldLabel;
    private String fieldType;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FormResponse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_field_id")
    private FormField formField;
    private Object responseValue;

    @AssertTrue(message = "This field should be filled with a string.")
    boolean isAssertTrue() {
        if (formField.getFieldType().equals("short_answer")) {
            return responseValue instanceof String;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Whenever a user fill a form field `isAssertTrue()` method checks if it is the same type with the `fieldType`. However, this program gives error due to this line: `private Object responseValue;` and the error is: `[Unable to determine SQL type name for column 'response_value' of table 'form_response': No type mapping for org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes code: 2000 (JAVA_OBJECT)]`. I can understand why it gives error but I can't think another way to validate the `FieldType` because `responseValue` could be any type of value. I don't think this is the best approach to make this kind of validation but I can't think any other way to do that either. How can I validate if the `FieldType` matches with the `responseValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a basic field as an `Object` out-of-the box, without further type definition, that's why Hibernate says it does not find any matching SQL type. To use custom types, check [Custom Types in Hibernate and the @Type Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types).

For simple use cases, you could store responseValue as a `String` or `byte[]` and use serialization/deserialization mechanisms to write/read this field.

Using `String responseValue`, you could validate with that kind of logic:

```
@AssertTrue(message = "This field should be filled with a positive integer.")
boolean isValidPositiveInteger() {
    if (formField.getFieldType().equals("positive-integer")) {
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(responseValue);
            return i > 0;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) [
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But as you said, it's not the best approach to build that kind of thing if it is intended to handle large and complex forms.

If relational data storage is not a constraint, dealing with dynamic forms is often simpler with JSON (all recent RDBMS also have strong JSON support, and you can map easily manipulate JSON with JPA/Hibernate).

Btw, you should look at products like [form.io](https://form.io)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Hibernate does not know what DB column type a Java `Object` should be mapped to. The `Object` could for example be a string, an `Embeddable` or another `Entity`. All three are represented in a different way in the DB layer.

You could try mapping it to JSON, then you can have primitive values as well as complete objects in there. Check out [Vlad Mihalcea's guide on how to store JSON in DB columns](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-map-json-jpa-hibernate/).